# Events on react-leaflet v3

Tags: react-leaflet-v3

I just want to catch the click event **on the map**. I'm either finding examples for v2 which won't work on v3, or very clear examples that work on plain leaflet but not quite in REACT-leaflet. The documentation on react-leaflet does not explain the examples so I don't know what it's happening here, if someone could please explain, it'd mean a lot to me.

My questions are:
1- how to catch the click event on the map, not on a marker.
And what's the explanation for this code:
2- what does "map.locate" do
3- and what is locationfound

The example obviously works, but since I don't understand how, I can't modify it to suit my needs.
Is there a way to have the documentation updated and expanded? I'm really tired and frustrated with this. Please help.
(Code is taken from https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-events)

```
function LocationMarker() {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(null)
  const map = useMapEvents({
    click() {
      map.locate()
    },
    locationfound(e) {
      setPosition(e.latlng)
      map.flyTo(e.latlng, map.getZoom())
    },
  })

  return position === null ? null : (
    <Marker position={position}>
      <Popup>You are here</Popup>
    </Marker>
  )
}

render(
  <MapContainer
    center={{ lat: 51.505, lng: -0.09 }}
    zoom={13}
    scrollWheelZoom={false}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
    <LocationMarker />
  </MapContainer>,
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay since nobody was helping, I kept on reading for a couple more days, and I understood the following:
1- how to catch the click event on the map, not on a marker.
You create a function that encapsulates your marker and returns it, within it you use the useMapEvents hooks, which takes a list of events as keys of an object:

```
useMapEvents({
    click() {
      ...
    },
    locationfound(e) {
    ...
    }
}
```

You can also do it as arrow functions such as the code shown here -> https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map

```
function MyComponent() {
  const map = useMapEvents({
    click: () => {
     ...
    },
    locationfound: (location) => {
      ...
    },
  })
  return null
}
```

This one returns null because it's just used to capture the events, but you might as well return a marker.

2- what does "map.locate" do?
It finds the location of the device it's running on, same as what "vanilla" leaflet does. See here: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-locate

3- and what is locationfound?
It is a "location event":

- locationerror ErrorEvent  Fired when geolocation (using the locate method) failed.
- locationfound LocationEvent   Fired when geolocation (using the locate method) went successfully.
  See: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#locationevent

I think the documentation needs some work, I hope to understand this to a point where I can help write. Sadly we only find code samples with no explanation on what they do.
Thank you.